# Spring MVC: Automatically return back to the same page upon binding errors

Tags: java, spring, validation, error-handling

I use the following piece of code in every controller method that saves an object:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user/saveX", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveX(@Valid @ModelAttribute("myCommand") MyCommand myCommand) {
  if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
    return "/user/saveX";
  }
  ...
  ...
}
```

I always send the user back to the same page as in `return "/user/saveX";` and display the binding errors, so I repeat this code in most controller methods.

I want to send this response `return "/user/saveX";` automatically when bindingResult has errors after validation. Is there a way to centralize this behavior with an interceptor or a filter?

Comment: I think maybe you can try `jQuery` `validate()`, this can validate the form on submitting, there's an option `remote` for calling controller method to validate. [validate-remote](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/)

Answer (score 0):

You should looking for AOP programming paradigm integrated in Spring.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop